# Rendering to BufferStrategy gives absolutely no output despite following instructions

Tags: java, 3d, software-rendering

I am following [this YouTube tutorial by TheCherno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKbZECPjQs0) to make 3D graphics using Java Standard Library.

Display.java

```java
package aritro;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1545751462933395031L;
    static int HEIGHT = 500, WIDTH = 800;
    static String title = "Minefront Pre-Alpha 0.0.1";
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    //private Render render;
    private Screen screen;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private int pixels[];

    public Display() {
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    private void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        System.out.println("Working...");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            tick();
            render();
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        
        screen.render();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }

}
```

This class is the main class which renders to the JFrame. The two helper classes `Render.java` and `Screen.java`.

Render.java

```java
package aritro.graphics;

public class Render {
    public int height, width;
    public int pixels[];

    public Render(int _width, int _height) {
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        pixels = new int[width * height];
    }

    public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
            int yPix = y + yOffset;
            for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
                int xPix = x + xOffset;
                pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = render.pixels[x + y * width];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screen.java

```java
package aritro.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen extends Render {
    private Render test;

    public Screen(int _width, int _height) {
        super(_width, _height);
        Random random = new Random();
        test = new Render(256, 256);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256 * 256; i++) {
            test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        draw(test, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

But unlike the the end of the video, I just get the blank grey screen instead of a black one with a pitch of randomly colored pixels.

Can someone point the mistake in the code which is causing the problems?

EDIT : Someone pointed out that I had initialized running to false in void start which did not initiate the game loop. but even after setting it to true, it doesn't work.

[image]

this is the blank screen.
Java version used - Java14.0.0.1

Comment: Do not edit your solution into the question. Instead, add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line thread.start() to void start() else the thread doesn't start

Answer (score 2):

In `start` you do `running = false;` which means that when `run` gets called, the gameloop will never activate and hence your actual rendering code will never run. In the linked video the code in `start` sets `running` to `true`.

Comment: ok. will correct

Comment: @AritroShome if this solved your problem, you should consider [marking it as the accepted answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 didn't solve